# UDP concurrency in Java can't handle multiple clients

Tags: java, concurrency, udp

Here is my code:

```
public class UDPServer implements Runnable{
    DatagramSocket socket;
    Logger logger;
    
    public UDPServer(DatagramSocket socket, Logger logger) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.logger=logger;
    }
    
    public static void handleEchoClient(DatagramSocket socket, Logger logger) throws IOException {
        
        int totalBytesEchoed=0;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[32], 32);
        socket.receive(packet);
        
        String s=new String(packet.getData()).trim();
        totalBytesEchoed=s.length();
        logger.info("Client " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() +", echoed " + totalBytesEchoed + " bytes.");
        socket.send(packet); 

        
    }
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            handleEchoClient(socket, logger);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int servPort = 3444;
    
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(servPort);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[32], 32);
    Executor servis = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("practical");
    
    
    servis.execute(new UDPServer(socket, logger));
    servis.execute(new UDPServer(socket, logger));
    

}
}
```

It works fine with 1 client, but it doesn't support 2 clients.
Thanks in advance.

Ignore this: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: "Ignore this: It looks like your post is mostly code;" -- your post could benefit from a discussion of your logic and the rationale behind sharing a single socket between two tasks on an executor without further coordination. Further, consider using a debugger to validate the state of your program and to check if any of your assumptions about the program's behavior are in fact correct.

Comment: This problem is why god invented TCP.  Why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

You have only one socket, and you send every reply to that socket's remote address. So there is no way your code can send replies to two different places.

If you want to handle more than one client, you need to track the various remote addresses you are communicating with and send replies to the appropriate client's remote address.